# Catching more than one exception in one try-except block

Tags: python, exception

in simple try-except block we can catch only first exception
But what should i do, when i want to catch every exception? How can i gather all errors?

Example, here we have 2 errors, ZeroDivision and Overflow, but raise will return only first, ZeroDivision, whether i print or write in log file or raise error

```
try:
    test_number, test_number_2 = 1/0, 16.**256
except *(ArithmeticError) as errors:
    for error in errors.exceptions:
        print(error)
```

result - division by zero

expected - division by zero
(34, 'Result too large')

Comment: There will never be more than one exception. When`1/0` gets an error, it won't execute `16.**256`

Comment: i know, that this is the basic approach, but maybe i can reraise, or make something with it?

Comment: You may find [PEP 654 - Exception Groups and except*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) interesting

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what you want to do when some operations succeed and others fail.  One possibility might be to gather all of the successes and the errors into data structures so you can iterate over them after you've tried all of the calculations:

```
successes = {}
errors = {}

for var, calc in (
    ('test_number', lambda: 1/0),
    ('test_number_2', lambda: 16.**256),
):
    try:
        successes[var] = calc()
    except ArithmeticError as e:
        errors[var] = e

for e in errors.values():
    print(e)

# division by zero
# (34, 'Result too large')
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as an exception occurs, that statement stops and it goes to the `except` block. So the overflow never occurs because the division by zero ends the statement.

If you want to catch both errors, you have to execute them sequentially, with separate `try/except` blocks.

```
errors = []
try:
    test_number = 1/0
except ArithmeticError as error:
    errors.append(error)
try:
    test_number2 = 16.**256
except ArithmeticError as error:
    errors.append(error)
for error in errors:
    print(error)
```